# Deserialization of enums: disallow deserialization from ordinal number

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson

I have an issue with serializing enums. I want the de-serialization to work only for the specified values(01,02,03) in the enum and not for the ordinal number. This can be quite confusing as shown in the example below. Is there some option or configuration for that? I'm using jackson in spring and I first noticed this behavior in version 3.1.x

Code sample:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
 println(objectMapper.readValue("{ \"value\": \"01\" }}", TestClass::class.java))
 println(objectMapper.readValue("{ \"value\": \"1\" }}", TestClass::class.java)) //this should fail
}

data class TestClass(val value: TestEnum)
enum class TestEnum(@JsonValue val value: String) {
 FIRST("01"),
 SECOND("02"),
 THIRD("03")
}
```

Output:

```
TestClass(value=FIRST)
TestClass(value=SECOND)
```

Dependencies used:

```
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2"
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.15.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The config option:

```
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS, true)
```

solves this issue.